Cannot import module (python)
I try to install external python packages using Pycharm and I got an OSError: It said Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt
I try to Set the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable. But first, You has to import certifi. which is came to the same error.
I cannot install any package. But in the example, I try to install colorgram module.
as example, I try to install colorgram.py
my screen when install colorgram
Ps. I have already upgrade pip to the latest version.
I already upgrade pip to the latest version.
I think the problem is C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt is not valid

You can resolve the OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle issue by setting the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable to the correct CA bundle path. Here's how:
Locate the CA bundle file path using Python:
import certifi

print(certifi.where())
Set the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable:
set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\Path\To\ca-bundle.crt

Alternatively, reinstall the certifi package:
pip install --upgrade certifi

Or specify the CA bundle path directly when installing packages:
pip install --cert C:\Path\To\ca-bundle.crt colorgram.py

This should fix the issue with installing Python packages.

i can't install any package including certifi. I have try to do the following method. But the problem came to cannot install any package.

Fix for Windows 10,
Reason: postgresql installation somehow updated the system environment Variable.
Fix in two steps(worked for me):
Update the system environment CURL_CA_BUNDLE variable with cacert.pem path present in Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem.
Note add the full path, in my case C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem
